What is the trade union for postdocs working in Germany?
I have an urgent matter to solve at my job as a postdoctoral researcher in a German university. However, I do not speak German and I do not know what is the relevant trade union to contact.

While there are unions that represent researchers in German academia (GEW, ver.di), depending on the kind of issue you are looking for something more local:
For general representation of employee interests this is often called "(Wissenschaftlicher) Personalrat" or "Personalrat der wissenschaftlichen Beschäftigten", for example at RWTH Aachen, TU Berlin or TU Dortmund.

can you elaborate on how do the two differ?

This explains it quite well: Basically the unions do not have local representations, but operate across companies (e.g. negotiating wages) - in practice the Personalrat is likely to contain union-affiliated members.

(In case you were asking about the different names: Just a matter of naming, although sometimes there may be separate councils for scientific employees versus everyone else)
